# Validate upload size to prevent HTTP Exception

Tags: asp.net

I am building an application with an integrated audio upload, though now I have the problem that my application is running into System.Web.HttpException: Maximum request length exceeded when uploading audio files over 10MB, as I have configured in my web.config

```
<httpRuntime maxRequestLength="10485">
```

I know about the possibility to increase the request limits in order to prevent this exception, but instead of allowing larger files I want to catch those and prevent their HTTP request.

It may be possible to validate the size client side, but as the client side validation can be bypassed I am looking for a server side validation that doesn't requires me to increase the limits.

Comment: you want to prevent the request on the server by...processing the request?

Comment: What I mean is that every request with files above 10MB results in an exception. So I am looking for a server side validation that does not allow those files to cause this exception.

Comment: what would it do instead? You might need to implement your own IHttpModule